# Handling the multiple select statement in an ng-repeat div

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="data1 in data.results ">
          <div class="col" >{{$index}}</div>
          <div class="col">{{data1.item_name}}</div>
          <div class="col">
          <select ng-model = "value" ng-change = "callUsers(value)">
           <option value = "" selected>Choose a process</option>
                <option ng-repeat='proces in data.process' >{{proces.name}}</option>
              </select>

          </div>
          <div class="col">
          <select ng-model = "value1" ng-change = "selectedEmployee(value1)">
           <option value = "" selected>Select User</option>
                <option value ="" ng-repeat='employee in employeeList' >{{employee.firstName}}</option>
              </select>

          </div>
    </div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.callUsers = function(code){ 
for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.process.length; i++){ 
 if($scope.data.process[i].name == code){ 
  var param = { 
   'process' : $scope.data.process[i].code 
  } 

  AssignOrderService.getEmployees(param) 
   .success(function(data) { 
   $ionicLoading.hide(); 
   if(data.length>0){ 
   $scope.employeeList = data; 
 } 

}).error(function(data) { 
$ionicLoading.hide(); 
}); 

} 
} 
} 
 $scope.selectedEmployee = function (employee){ 
var myIsolatedEmployee = angular.copy(employee); 
console.log(myIsolatedEmployee); 
}
```

When I change any process I'm getting the List of employees and showing it through the employeeList.

But the problem here is, as there are many select statement within employeeList scope, when I change one select option value of the process,  employeeList is automatically updating.

How to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are not isolating the employee list as you should. Therefore, you must declare the list and stuff inside it's context (i.e. `data1`) and it should work fine.

On the html you must add `data1` to identify the context like `ng-change="callUsers(value, data1)"`. Also, now you must iterate the employee list from the `data1` which is isolated now like `ng-repeat='employee in data1.employeeList'`.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="data1 in data.results ">
   <div class="col" >{{$index}}</div>
   <div class="col">{{data1.item_name}}</div>
   <div class="col">
      <select ng-model="value" ng-change="callUsers(value, data1)">
         <option value="" selected>Choose a process</option>
         <option ng-repeat='proces in data.process' >{{proces.name}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <select ng-model = "data1.value1" ng-change="selectedEmployee(value1)">
         <option value = "" selected>Select User</option>
         <option value ="" ng-repeat='employee in data1.employeeList' >{{employee.firstName}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

And on the controller, instead of binding the employee list to the main scope, you bind it to the `data1` which is the isolated context of your loop.

```
$scope.callUsers = function (code, data1) {
    //$scope.employeeList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.process.length; i++) {

        if ($scope.data.process[i].name == code) {
            var param = {
                'process': $scope.data.process[i].code

            }

            AssignOrderService.getEmployees(param)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();

                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        data1.employeeList = data;
                    }

                }).error(function (data) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                });   
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: when I change the process I'm updating the employeeList with new set of values, so the previous selections is removing. I need the previous selection not changed. How can it be done?

Comment: When i did angular.copy the value is storing but on the view it has been changing

Comment: @KarthikYeruva umm, Would you mind updating your question with your controller code?

Comment: controller code of my employeeList variable? . actually I'm doing angular.copy in my controller but how to update it on the view?

Comment: I mean, the Stackoverflow question. So that I can sse your controller code and understand why is your variable being changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126611/discussion-between-karthik-yeruva-and-lenilson-de-castro).